# SQL query to get 2 values from table 1 and join all possible option from table 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get value from table1 and join all matching value from table2. The table1 has to be limited to 2 rows, but expecting output should own all matching values for those two ids.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: In the title you say limit to 10 values and in the question you say 2 values and it is not clear how many you limit it to in your example.

Comment: I will anyway make it dynamic, but you have point. Changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a subquery:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from (select t1.*
      from table1 t1
      limit 10
     ) t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.table1_id;
```

Note:  This returns two *arbitrary* rows.  Normally, you would have an `order by` to better specify the rows.  And use `order by rand()` for random rows.

Answer (score 0):

if you want all the value in join for only two row of table 1 you can use a subqiuery with limit 2

```
select b.id, a.value, b.value2, b.table1_ID
from (
    select * from table1
    limit 2

) a 
inner join table2 on aid = b.table1_ID
```